# Drop Down Menu doesn't Show on IE

Tags: html, css

I have made this question: [Menu with 2 levels disapear the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497919/) and that's solved. But  my menu with sub-items does not work on IE8.

And i dont know where i'm wrong with this.

Here is the updated link of my menu: [Here](http://www.alsite.com.br/credacif/topo.html) is working example.

can Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dropdown menu is not working because it is firing in Quirks mode. Add a proper DOCTYPE and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Edit: here is a demo of your menu with the proper markup working just fine in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/4ApsQ/show/

Comment: @Preston - having a proper `DOCTYPE` declaration and making sure your HTML is at least [structurally valid](http://validator.w3.org/) are critical to staying out of Quirks Mode. Even if you don't fully validate to standards compliance, you at least need to make sure the DOM is built in a predictable way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if we could see an extract of your HTML and the CSS that you're using for this task. But, in general, if I understand your problem/question correctly, these are the two things to watch out for in your styles:

**z-index** and **position**

Here's an example:

```
#divStayTopLeft
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

If you make your z-index (reasonably) high enough, then your menu will remain on top of other elements.